# Reordering sections, removing or adding items and tracking locations in UITableView's datasource for perfect animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Here is the data structure I use for items in UITableView:

- Array of NSMutableDictionary items.
- Those items also have an array of NSMutableDictionary items too.

After setting the main array as the datasource of UITableView, I do not want to use [tableView reloadData] as I want it to animate and where possible, I want to keep content-offset the user is currently on.

I already have this scheme working but I replace the main array and use reloadData.

To do what I want, I tried removing sections those do not exist in the new main array from the current array and track that section index so I can remove those indexes from UITableView in `beginUpdates`.

However, everything became very complex. Adding/Removing/Moving sections and then the same for the items inside them. I couldn't even do this perfectly for just the sections, as section's may be added ,moved or may be completely removed..

What are the best practices for perfectly tracking location changes and existence of items in dataSource to be used in `beginUpdates` - `endUpdates` and to really change physical existence and positions of those items in the dataSource object.

Maybe I couldn't explain it clearly but to summarize, I want to know best practices for updating a table without reloadData.

**edit 1:**

Please note: I know how to and can detect if an item is new or changed. The problem is tracking the location changes (additions,removals or index/section changes (moves))

Comment: How are the changes made? Are multiple changes made at the same time? What are the sections hade up from? Can you change your data storage / structure?

Comment: @Wain: I download a json file from my server and I do it periodically. (They can not happen at the same time as I check if there already is an active download/update from the server). Sections are composed of NSMutableDictionary items with "key"=>"keyName", "data"=>Array of other NSMutableDictionary items those will be used as the content of that section. I can differentiate sections by checking "keyName" and I can differantiate items in each section with isEqualToDictionary (matching contents, instead of pointers)

Comment: Personally, I'd use RestKit to read the JSON in and store it in Core Data, then use an FRC to manage the table view...